# YouTube Live - Are Replay/DVR Function users counted as "live viewer"?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

If you open a broadcast "event" with YouTube live, users are able to use a playback feature which allows them to watch the past 3 hours of the broadcast without leaving the interface - you simply can watch back like you'd do with a vod, but you are still in the broadcast you simply have control over the past buffered minutes.

Question is, are those people counted in the "view counter" on the bottom-right or not?

The API docs also never clearly specify if the use of the replay function effects the live view counter in the broadcast interface.

*My hypothesis is that every active broadcasting viewer is counted into the "live view counter" no matter if he skips back few minutes or not as otherwise there must be huge jumps and drops in live view counters for larger broadcasts and it would skew the real-time broadcast metrics significantly.*

Answer (score 0):

YouTube is vague about what constitutes a view on purpose to preview view fraud.

I've run a few tests on live events and I believe anyone currently viewing a live even from the live player, even if their playhead is a few hours back, is considered a "live" viewer.  After an event has ended, however, views are no longer counted as live views and are considered video views.  The total number of views is generally incorrect until the live event finishes processing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and that makes sense to prevent abuse with simply denying simple access to the background processing methods.

However, I look at those metrics for marketing and sales purposes as also as justification data. So, I at least need to get a specific statement if that hypothesis is true.

I came to a similar result like you, but I also know of few people who ran very unscientific tests that came to a different result - like they saw a drop if one rewinds just 5 minutes back.

I hope that someone simply knows more or even works for Youtube dev department.